# How to forward/route packets via wireguard overlay network?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, wireguard

My question is related to basics in network routing and iptables, and is probably due to my lack of understanding on how I should set this up.

I have established an overlay network between hosts using wireguard, where one is behind a Router/NAT. In so far the overlay network works well, and each host can talk to the others.

Now, I would like to make Host A a gateway to the private network, but I am miserably failing to do so.

Can you maybe help me unravel the mystery that is iptables forwarding?

#### 3 Networks

The overlay network of the VPN is `169.254.0.0/24` and the private network behind the router is a `192.168.0.0/24`.

- The internet
- The overlay network (`169.254.0.0/24`, running on Wireguard)
- The private network (`192.168.0.0/24`)

#### 4 Hosts

- VPN Server

  `wg0: 169.254.0.1`
- Client

  `wg0: 169.254.0.2`
- Host A

  `wg0: 169.254.0.3`
  `eth0: 192.168.0.33`
- Host B

  `eth0: 192.168.0.53`

In order to illustrate the real network, here is this picture:
[image: real network]

And here is the overlay network:
[image: overlay network]

At which, my Client is failing to send packets to Host B via Host A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working configuration. Phew, I actually got it myself, but it took me a while to get things right.

#### Client

I had to make sure that the peer (VPN Server) is allowed to use the `192.168.178.0/24` range.

```
[Interface]
Address = 169.254.0.2/32
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 51280

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 169.254.0.1/32, 192.168.178.0/24
Endpoint = ...:51280
```

#### VPN Server

I just had to forward packets from the `tun0` interface and `MASQUERADE` them.
Furthermore, I also added the `192.168.178.0/24` network to the `AllowedIPs` of Host A.

```
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Wireguard configuration:

```
[Interface]
Address = 169.254.0.1/32
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 51280

[Peer]
Endpoint = ...:51280
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIps = 169.254.0.2/32

[Peer]
Endpoint = ...:51280
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIps = 169.254.0.3/32, 192.168.178.0/24
```

#### Host A

There I needed to accept forwarding pakets on both interfaces. And I would masquerade pakets on `eth0`.

```
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Wireguard wise, the configuration is nothing special. It is simply connected to the VPN server.

```
[Interface]
Address = 169.254.0.3/32
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 51280

[Peer]
Endpoint = ...:51280
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIps = 169.254.0.1/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

However, there was one **major pitfall** when working with Host A (which is behind a Router/NAT). The VPN server must know the endpoint (public ip + port) of Host A in order to send pakets to it.
The Router would loose state after a while, and thus the VPN Server would no longer be able to connect to Host A.

I fixed this, by adding the `PersistentKeepalive` setting to the `[Peer]` section of the VPN server on Host A.
(Thanks to @A.B from comments to point this out.)

> I wonder how to solve that if both are behind a Router/NAT. Damn, that is complicated.

Comment: Wireguard has a keepalive option, look for PersistentKeepalive  in `man wg`. Also I'm not sure it's good practice to use IPv4LL (in 169.254.0.0/16) addresses, since they are supposed to be non-routable.

Comment: @A.B thanks for the notice, the keepalive option is highly appreciated, I will also edit the answer to not mislead others. I choose the link-local range, because of that trait. I wanted a range that is not public but also very likely never used in any private networks. Are there better options? I had the occasional network conflict when using ranges from `10.0.0.0/8` or `192.168.0.0/16`.

Comment: Well, thinking about it, IPv6 would obviously be an alternative.

Comment: @Overbryd Please accept your own answer as an answer.